Using scripting languages other than Python on Digital Earth Australia Sandbox
I might be missing something obvious here, but am I able to use other scripting languages like for example R in the DEA (Digital Earth Australia) Sandbox?
For clarification the DEA sandbox is located here: https://app.sandbox.dea.ga.gov.au/hub/login?next=%2Fhub%2F
I can only see the ability to run Python and Python related scripts on the Sandbox.

Seems obvious, but did you actually contact the EarthObservationMail email address in the link you provided If you have any questions or concerns, contact us at... ?  Other than that would agree with your findings that the Sandbox is a Python only environment.  If you find different you can document it as an answer here

The DEA Sandbox is a Python-only environment. However, it is possible to access Digital Earth Australia data outside of the Sandbox with R, using a combination of DEA's Explorer STAC API, rstac and gdalcubes! See code below (also available in the Gist here):
"""
This code demonstrates how to load Digital Earth Australia Sentinel-2 Analysis Ready Data into R.

It uses `rstac` to search for available data for a time and location using DEA's STAC endpoint,
and `gdalcubes` to load and analyse the data.

Functionality includes:

    * Creating a custom pixel grid to reproject data into
    * Apply a cloud mask using the "s2cloudless" cloud mask
    * Combine data into seasonal composites
    * Create an RGB animation
    * Convert data to NDVI and plot across time as a timeseries plot and animation

Inspired by content in the following tutorial:
https://gdalcubes.github.io/source/tutorials/vignettes/gc02_AWS_Sentinel2.html
"""

library(magrittr)
library(colorspace)
library(rstac)
library(gdalcubes)

# Set parallelisation and AWS credentials to allow anonymous access
Sys.setenv("AWS_NO_SIGN_REQUEST" = "YES")
gdalcubes_options(parallel = 16)

# Set params
time = "2023-01-01/2023-12-31"
bbox = list(left=149.335, top=-35.31, right=149.375, bottom=-35.35)

# Connect to DEA STAC endpoint
items <- stac("https://explorer.dea.ga.gov.au/stac") %>%
  
  # Set up search query for Sentinel-2 data in time period and bounding box
  stac_search(collections = c("ga_s2am_ard_3", "ga_s2bm_ard_3"),
              datetime = time,
              bbox = bbox,
              limit = 1000) %>%

  # Run search query
  get_request()

# Create gdalcube image collection, filtering to specific bands and cloud cover
s2_collection <- stac_image_collection(items$features,
                                       asset_names = c("nbart_red", "nbart_green", "nbart_blue", "nbart_nir_1", "oa_s2cloudless_mask"),
                                       property_filter = function(x) {x[["eo:cloud_cover"]] < 50})

# Creat a custom pixel grid and temporal aggregation
cube_grid <- cube_view(srs = "EPSG:4326", 
                         extent = list(left=bbox$left, 
                                       right=bbox$right, 
                                       top=bbox$top, 
                                       bottom=bbox$bottom,
                                       t0="2023-01-01",
                                       t1="2023-12-31"), 
                         dx = 0.0001,
                         dy = 0.0001, 
                         dt = "P3M",  # create seasonal composites
                         resampling = "nearest", 
                         aggregation = "median")

# Create a cloud mask from the s2cloudless cloud mask layer, treating nodata and cloud as bad
s2_mask = image_mask("oa_s2cloudless_mask", values = c(0, 2))

# Resample satellite data into grid after applying cloud mask
s2_cube <- raster_cube(image_collection = s2_collection, 
                       view = cube_grid, 
                       mask = s2_mask,
                       chunking = c(1, 2024, 2024))

# Plot results in RGB
plot(s2_cube, rgb = c(4, 2, 1), zlim = c(0, 2000))
animate(s2_cube, rgb = c(4, 2, 1), zlim = c(0, 2000), fps = 4)


# Example NDVI analysis
ndvi <- s2_cube %>%
  apply_pixel("(nbart_nir_1-nbart_green)/(nbart_nir_1+nbart_green)", "NDVI")

ndvi %>%
  reduce_space("min(NDVI)", "max(NDVI)", "mean(NDVI)") %>%
  plot(join.timeseries = TRUE)

ndvi_col = function(n) { rev(sequential_hcl(n, "Green-Yellow")) }
ndvi %>%
  animate(key.pos = 1, zlim = c(-0.2,1), col = ndvi_col, nbreaks = 100, fps = 4)




Awesome - appreciate the answer and the additional code!

Awesome - feel free to upvote this answer, and happy to help out if you run into any issues!
